# angular + firebase: what component to contain firebase auth?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular6

I'm building an Angular 6 app and need to add Firebase authentication. The app component contains a  element and a  component.

Which component should import the AngularFireAuth component? The app.component.ts or the navbar.component.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auth service!

This is something that needs to be abstracted away in a service, not a component. A service that is long lived as has max 1 instance per app (singleton?).

Comment: thanks and I agree. Your response helped me find a detailed solution. (Sorry I can't vote on this answer yet, but hopefully others will agree).